# php two dimensional array permutation...; single phonics have multiple letters in english

Tags: php, combinations, permutation

i have array of phonics having multiple alternate English letters

```
$q[0][0]="c";
$q[1][0]="k";
$q[2][0]="q";

---
$q[0][1]="u";
$q[1][1]="a";

--

$q[0][2]="t"
```

---

i have table of words which contain words
cut
put
tag

i want to permute above 2d array and generate query having all possible words as

```
cut
qat
kut
--
cat
qut
kat
----
```

or we may include also and continue above series for programmatic logic requirements

```
tac
tuc
tak
---
tuq
taq
tuk
---
act
ukt
uct
---
```

all i need is array variable like $word{$i] having all above possible permutations words.
when i would run above query possible word, it will only find "cut" in table and i would replace "ڪَٽ" with "cut".... yes its roman translitration
the programming still yet i have tried is

```
<input type="text" name="leng" id="leng" value="" ><input type='submit' name='submit'></form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++){ //3 is number of listboxes or length of given string

        //echo $list[$i]; 

        for ($x=0; $x<= $_POST['leng']; $x++){
?>
<script>
document.getElementById("leng").value = document.getElementById("<?php echo $list[$i]; ?>").length;
 </script>
```

> // i have made three list boxes named list0, list1, list3 in above
>   line
>       list0="c, q, k"
>       list1="u, a"
>       list2="t"

```
 <?php
            //echo "($i-i)--  ($x-X) <BR>";
            echo $q[$i][$x]."<BR>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete program i have tried....
the thing is "if some one write "fahad" string into English, then i have had to translitrate it into sindhi and in sindhi language there are multiple alternates of single english letter like f has 2alternates, a has trhee alternates َ، آ، ا and h has three  alternates ه، ح، ھ and d has three alternates د، ڊ، ڏ
all alternates are written into database table against english aletter....... first i search each letter into letter alternate table..... if found i put one by one to list/select boxes.... all listboxes are equal to length number of "fahad" so 5 listboxes are generated.....
and put current listbox's length into $_POST['leng'] textbox.....
now i do permutation of $q array on this [permutation of multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225926/how-to-create-a-permutation-of-two-dimensional-array)

then after i calculate each 5 word length

```
global $servername;
    global $username;
    global $password;
    global $dbname;


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "tsrs";
//////////////////////

global $q;
$q=array();

//////////////////////
for ($n=0; $n<=strlen("fahad"); $n++){

$i=substr("fahad", $n, 1);
//echo $i;

/////////////////////
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM duplicate WHERE engletter='$i' order by id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
global $m;
$m=0;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$altrntcount=$result->num_rows; 


    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $q[$n][$m]=$row['sinletter']    ;
    echo $q[$n][$m]."<BR>";

    $m=$m+1;
    }
    }

}
echo "<form method='post'>";

for ($n=0; $n<=strlen("fahad")-1; $n++){
$list[$n]="list".$n;
echo $list[$n];
echo "
<select name=\"".$list[$n]."\" id=\"".$list[$n]."\">";

for ($m=0; $m<=$altrntcount-1; $m++){
if ($q[$n][$m]<>""){
echo "<option value=\"".$q[$n][$m]."\">".$q[$n][$m]."</option>";

}

}
echo "</select>";  
}?> 
<input type="text" name="leng" id="leng" value="1" ><input type='submit' name='submit'></form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

for($i=0; $i<=strlen("fahad")-1; $i++){

    //echo $list[$i]; 





for ($x=0; $x<= $_POST['leng']+1; $x++){

    ?>

    <script>



    document.getElementById("leng").value = document.getElementById("<?php echo $list[$i]; ?>").length;

 </script>
 <?php

    echo $i."-i: I : ".$x.": X <BR>";

    echo $q[$i][$x];

}

}
echo "<h1>".($_POST['leng'])."zzz</h1>";







echo "-----<BR><BR><BR>++++++";



}
    ?>

<?php
global $q;


//$arrStart = array(
 //array('ف', 'ڦ', 'په'),
   // array('ح', 'ه'),
    //array('د', 'ڊ','ڏ')
//);

//$arrStart= $q[$i][$x];
$arrPositions =     array();
$arrResult = array();

//get a starting position set for each sub array
for ($i = 0; $i < count($q); $i++)
    $arrPositions[] = 0;

//repeat until we've run out of items in $q[0]
while (array_key_exists($arrPositions[0], $q[0])) {
    $arrTemp = array();
    $blSuccess = true;

    //go through each of the first array levels
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($q); $i++) {
        //is there a item in the position we want in the current array?
        if (array_key_exists($arrPositions[$i], $q[$i])) {
            //add that item to our temp array
            $arrTemp[] = $q[$i][$arrPositions[$i]];
        } else {
            //reset this position, and raise the one to the left
            $arrPositions[$i] = 0;
            $arrPositions[$i - 1]++;
            $blSuccess = false;
        }
    }

    //this one failed due to there not being an item where we wanted, skip to next go
    if (!$blSuccess) continue;

    //successfully adding nex line, increase the right hand count for the next one
    $arrPositions[count($q) - 1]++;

    //add our latest temp array to the result
    $arrResult[] = $arrTemp;

}



    print_r($arrResult);





    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

for($i=0; $i<=count($arrResult)-1; $i++){

    //echo $list[$i]; 


?>

    <script>



    document.getElementById("leng").value = document.getElementById("<?php echo $list[$i]; ?>").length;

 </script>
 <?php  

for ($x=0; $x<= $_POST['leng']+2; $x++){






    //echo $i."-i: I : ".$x.": X <BR><BR><BR>";

    echo $arrResult[$i][$x];

}
echo "<BR><BR>";
}
echo "<h1>".($_POST['leng'])."zzz</h1>";







echo "-----<BR><BR><BR>++++++";



}
```